# Iterate over two numpy arrays of different sizes as a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In short, I have a sort-of Pythonic way of iterating across two dimensions, but since it's with big numbers and multiple arrays, I'd like a `numpy` version of `tile_iter`, instead of a dual for loop in a list comprehension. I'd like it to be the same values as shown, but within a 2D numpy array of the same shape (without just converting my current array with an `np.array` wrapper - I'm trying to avoid list comprehension)

Here's a minimized, simplified version of what I currently have:

```py
import numpy as np

x_cam_screen_range = np.linspace((6, 0), (18, 1), 3)
y_cam_screen_range = np.linspace((-3, 0), (3, 1), 3)
tile_iter = [(x, screen_x, y, screen_y)
             for x, screen_x in x_cam_screen_range
             for y, screen_y in y_cam_screen_range]

# current list response:
# [(6.0, 0.0, -3.0, 0.0),
# (6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5),
# (6.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0),
# (12.0, 0.5, -3.0, 0.0),
# (12.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5),
# (12.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0),
# (18.0, 1.0, -3.0, 0.0),
# (18.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5),
# (18.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0)]
```

Is there a way I can create `tile_iter` in a numpy-friendly way? If there's an existing question that reflects this, I cannot for the life of me find it (but if you can, I'd be grateful).

Comment: May be you should provide an example of what you would expect as a result. I take it is not a numpy array of tuples, since that would be very inefficient. So, most probable solution for you is a broadcasting. Or maybe some usage of `meshgrid`

Comment: Updated the comment with the current result. I'd like it to be the same values, within a 2D numpy array of the same shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible answer, doing something quite similar to your list of tuple could be

```py
(np.linspace((0.5,0,0,0),(0.5,1,0,0), resolution_x)[:,None,:]+np.linspace((0,0,-0.37,0),(0,0,0.37,1),resolution_y)[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,4)
```

The 0,0 padding to linspace argument, so that + does all the broadcasting is probably some laziness on my behalf. It is probably possible to concatenate the 2 pair while broadcasting.

But the main idea is that doing an operation (here a `+`) between a `(resolution_x,1,4)` shaped array and a `(1,resolution_y,4)` shaped array usually (it is the case for +) makes numpy perform the double iteration of `resolution_x` and `resolution_y` to compute all the `resolution_x*resolution_y` possible combination. So, it is the numpy way to iterate a double loop. (that is, never ever white a `for` loop, but trick numpy to do it internally)

With your updated data, and splitting the computation in more that one line

```py
x_cam_screen_range = np.linspace((6, 0,0,0), (18, 1,0,0), 3)
y_cam_screen_range = np.linspace((0,0,-3, 0), (0,0,3, 1), 3)
tile_iter = (x_cam_screen_range[:,None,:]+y_cam_screen_range[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,4)
#array([[ 6. ,  0. , -3. ,  0. ],
#       [ 6. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
#       [ 6. ,  0. ,  3. ,  1. ],
#       [12. ,  0.5, -3. ,  0. ],
#       [12. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
#       [12. ,  0.5,  3. ,  1. ],
#       [18. ,  1. , -3. ,  0. ],
#       [18. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0.5],
#       [18. ,  1. ,  3. ,  1. ]])
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! And even works when the two range arrays are different sizes.